# How to split the number into given ranges accordingly (ranges are based on priority)?

Tags: algorithm, math, data-science, probability

Here is the scenario
Given requested amount 789
I have 4 warehouse. Warehouse 1 will be the highest priority and follow by warehouse 2 etc...
All warehouse have their own min and max stock amount to distribute.
Now I want to split the requested amount to fit the available ranges.
*Not necessary to utilize all the warehouse but the highest priority have to be utilize first.
*All warehouses only can use one time
Expecting answer as per below picture.

Is there any algorithm  to get me an answer ?> [400,189,200]
Thanks alot [image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fiC8.png)

Comment: What is the goal? Use the maximum warehouses possible?

Comment: The goal, is to use the maximum amount for each warehouse based on their min & max amount and also based on their priority. Warehouse 1 will be utilize first.

Comment: Example. if i choose 400 for the warehouse 1, then i wont be able to distribute 789. since the balance will split into 200 & 189 after 789 deducted 400. 200 can fit into warehouse 2 , but 189 wont be  able to find any available warehouse.

Comment: But if it's by priority the result should be 400, 189, 200... since it's preferable to get objetcs from 1 instead of 2

Comment: 189 in warehouse 2! It surpasses the minimum amount, which is 100.

Comment: Yes, samthegolden. 400, 189, 200 also acceptable.

Comment: Well, "also acceptable" doesn't make it deterministic. Either you have an algorithm or multiple...

Comment: Ya, my bad the correct answer will be 400,189,200. My brain went haywire. Do you have any ideas ? How to split it ? I have corrected the question

Comment: Check the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check if the maximum of the 1st warehouse covers the requested amount. If not, check if the max of 1 and 2 covers, if not, the max of 1,2 and 3... until it covers. Now you have `x` warehouses to use.
2. Start from the bottom now. Use the minimum possible from each warehouse until the top. Minimum of less priority warehouse, plus the minimum of 2nd less priority... The sum of all the minimums may not cover the requested amount, but let's proceed with that amount
3. Start adding from the more priority warehouse - add to the maximum of it. Does it cover?
4. If yes, remove (from that warehouse) until the requested amount is equal to the collected.
5. If not, Repeat steps 3 and 4 for the 2nd more priority warehouse, 3rd, 4th...

Comment: I have tried to understand your answer, but i don't get it from point 2 onward. After I have done the checking on point 1, the result will return warehouse 3.  What do you mean by start from bottom ?

Comment: does it answer you? @JunXiang

Comment: I got it until point 2 now. point 2 will return a result 600 (totalMin) . And then I will proceed with that amount 600 at point 3.  On point 3, you are saying add to the maximum of it. Is it  add the 0 to 100 (difference between min and max of warehouse 1) to the 600(totalMin) and check if the sum is covered the requested amount ?

Comment: Yes @JunXiang. And if it does not cover the requested amount, proceed with warehouse 2

Comment: Thanks ! I got it ad